# How can I perform Transformations on MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations) show how you can perform `Transformations` on a `LiveData` object? How can I perform a transformation like `map()` and `switchMap()` on a `MutableLiveData` object instead?

Answer (score 1):

MutableLiveData is just a subclass of LiveData.  Any API that accepts a LiveData will also accept a MutableLiveData, and it will still behave the way you expect.

Comment: I was about to vote to close this question but then I remember how poor is the doc on the subject, that is why I went with a lengthy answer

Comment: @cutiko I dunno, the API docs are pretty clear the MutableLiveData is just a subclass.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData

Comment: I think the clarity is half written text and half years of experience, if OP is not even adding an example the kind thing to do is assume confusion and try to help with that, but I see your point everything is technically there.

Comment: @cutiko I did think it should work out of the box, and several Google searches I made did show no one else had the same issue. But it wasn't working for my case, I will update the question shortly if appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way:

```
fun viewModelFun() = Transformations.map(mutableLiveData) {
    //do somethinf with it
}
```

Perhaps your problem is you dont know how does yor mutable live data fit on this.
In the recent update mutable live data can start with a default value

```
private val form = MutableLiveData(Form.emptyForm())
```

That should trigger the transformation as soon as an observer is attached, because it will have a value to dispatch.

Of maybe you need to trigger it once the observer is attached

```
fun viewModelFun(selection: String) = liveData {
     mutableLiveData.value = selection.toUpperCase
     val source = Transformations.map(mutableLiveData) {
        //do somethinf with it
     }
     emitSource(source)
}
```

And if you want the switch map is usually like this:

```
private val name = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun observeNames() = Transformations.switchMap(name) {
        dbLiveData.search(name) //a list with the names
}

fun queryName(likeName: String) {
    name.value = likeName
}
```

And in the view you would set a listener to the edit text of the search

```
searchEt.doAfterTextChange {...
    viewModel.queryName(text)
}
```